# How to increment value continuously on mouse hold using angularjs mouse events?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I want to increment value continuously until mouse hold on a button using angularjs.

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="add('increase');"></button>

$scope.add = function(operation) {
  bill.quantity += 1;
}
```

Comment: Can you show us what have you achieved so far?

Comment: You can use timeout to "count" the possible clicks made when the user holds the mouse down. Here's a sample code. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25180332/how-can-i-listen-for-a-click-and-hold-in-angularjs

Comment: `ng-lick` .... LAWL!!! Also, this will only increment once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per my understanding, what want to continuously increment value on `mouse pressed + hold`.

Your code

```
$scope.add = function(operation) {
  bill.quantity += 1;
}
```

will just increment value by one on click.

For what you want to achieve, you have to have 2 events.

- First, when to start update (`ng-mousedown`).
- Second, when to stop update (`ng-mouseup`).

Also, events are fired only once, so you need to use `setTimeout` to increment in timely fashion.

Also, updating value in a `setTimeout` does not reflect directly. You will have to use `$scope.$apply()`. Refer following post for reference: [AngularJS Input field not updating from setTimeout inside controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29719289/angularjs-input-field-not-updating-from-settimeout-inside-controller)

#### Demo

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/1sotth20/).

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
  var interval = null;
  $scope.bill = {
    quantity: 0
  };
  $scope.add = function(newVal) {
    console.log("Add");
    initInterval(newVal);
  }

  function initInterval(newVal) {
    if (!interval) {
      console.log("Interval start");
      interval = setInterval(function() {
        $scope.$apply(function() {
          $scope.bill.quantity += newVal;
        });
      }, 1000);
    }
  }

  $scope.clearInterval = function() {
    console.log("Interval cleared");
    if (interval) {
      window.clearInterval(interval);
      interval = null;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <p>{{bill.quantity}}</p>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-mousedown="add(1);" ng-mouseup="clearInterval()">Increment</button>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-mousedown="add(-1);" ng-mouseup="clearInterval()">Decrement</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Really you saved my day :)

Comment: @cheralathan I'm glad, I could help.